# Finishing authentication after user is prompted to change password

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

My SF app is only the login page. All the access of the data is done using SF REST API. Our login page is a custom VF page. The problem is when the user first logs in, she receives the change password page. After entering the change password page, the authentication loads back the login screen and the user has to enter the credentials again. How can I skip this extra login?﻿

The same problem happens when the user taps on forgot password. The app shows the login webview again and the user receives the email with temp password. After the user enters user/temp password, the change password view shows up. After the user enters the user/new password, the app never finishes the authentication and it keeps showing our login page again.